# `ssh -T` to VSTS(Azure Devops) authenticates successfully, but `git clone` fails

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I recently created a second key to access Visual Studio Team Services,

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

so I now have two keys:

```
id_github
id_vsts
```

Both keys seem to have been picked up by ssh: `ssh-add -l` lists both of them.

Next, I added `id_vsts.pub` to my VSTS account security. The key was properly added because requesting SSH terminal access authenticates properly:

```
Authentication for user with identifier "" was successful against account "my_account". 
Shell is not supported.
```

However, when I `git clone ssh://[user]@[host]:22/[repo]`, it fails!

```
Your Git command did not succeed.
Details:
        Public key authentication failed.
```

In an unexpected turn of events, if I use `id_github`'s public key, the clone succeeds. What's going on?

Comment: What detail steps you did? Do you add public key to VSTS (Profile>Security>SSH public keys) https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate#step-2--add-the-public-key-to-team-servicestfs

Comment: Updated question with more detailed steps, let me know if this helps @starain-MSFT

Comment: Do you Force SSH Client To Use Given Private Key? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/

Comment: No, I don't force the client. The command I use is `git clone ssh://[user]@[host]:22/[repo]`. The url is copied using the "copy to clipboard" icon. I was under the impression that all private keys are used in trying to authenticate.

Comment: What's the result if you force the client to use that private key. SSH -I?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll try again when I get home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to force the client to use specific private key, otherwise it uses the default one.

To check which private key file used for a host, you can run

```
ssh -v [host(e.g. test@test.visualstudio.com)]
```

One way is that you can configure it in the config file. (My steps for windows)

1. Run `touch .ssh/config` if there isn’t config file in .ssh folder
2. Open config file

code:

```
Host xx.visualstudio.com
  IdentityFile /c/Users/xx/.ssh/id_vsts
```

3. Open new command line and run `Git clone` command

Another way is that, you can run `ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa user@server.nixcraft.com` command.

More information, you can refer to this article: [Force SSH Client To Use Given Private Key](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/force-ssh-client-to-use-given-private-key-identity-file/) (identity file)

Comment: Excellent! ssh -v was the key to figuring out what was going on.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to the `~/.ssh/config` file for the VSO host did the trick.

Comment: Amazing, this did the trick for me too (after banging my head for an hour).

Comment: I looked for days for a solution! Github and anything else works fine, its only VSO (or whatever Microsoft is calling it, VSTS? TFS with Git?) that requires this setting.

Comment: Worked for me! More details here: https://superuser.com/a/272613/265248

Answer (score 0):

Apparently git uses only the first key provided, if that fails, git clone fails. My ssh config had a wildcard option with a key matching before the git key and therefore it did not work. After moving the git configuration to the top of .sss/config all is fine.