# Git: Public key authentication failed

Tags: git, azure-devops

When I want to use git on with azure devops (vsts) I can't use git clone, pull, push etc. I get the error:

> remote:
>   remote: Your Git command did not succeed.
>   remote: Details:
>   remote:     Public key authentication failed.
>   remote:
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

But when I use the command below it works, so the problem is not the key.
`ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/key; git push repo'`

When I do a git clone, push, pull etc I thought it goes through your .ssh dir to automatically check which key to use. Anybody any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar thread at [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/145027/cannot-do-git-operations-public-key-denied.html) which indicates this bug is fixed

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705553/ssh-t-to-vsts-authenticates-successfully-but-git-clone-fails

Comment: look at the official doc [I have multiple SSH keys. How do I use different SSH keys for different SSH servers or repos?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#q-i-have-multiple-ssh-keys--how-do-i-use-different-ssh-keys-for-different-ssh-servers-or-repos)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Fixed it by creating ~/.ssh/config and added:

```
Host xxx.visualstudio.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

Make sure to do chmod 0400 ~/.ssh/config

Comment: look at the official doc [I have multiple SSH keys. How do I use different SSH keys for different SSH servers or repos?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#q-i-have-multiple-ssh-keys--how-do-i-use-different-ssh-keys-for-different-ssh-servers-or-repos)

Answer (score 13):

I added in the ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[you private key file]
```

Answer (score 5):

My case was more tricky. VisualStudio.com banned my old ssh key and didn't bother to somehow notify me. Experimentally I figured out that I just need to add a new key and use *it* instead.

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/new_key
```

In ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/new_key
```

That worked.
Then fun thing was that they don't let you remove the old banned key from `SSH Keys` page.

Update:
With OpenSSH **8.9p1** that makes ssh-rsa keys by default, you may need to enable `ssh-rsa` in ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config.

```
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102410/4653540

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by adding the identity to the SSH provider with

`ssh-add [path to your private key]`

so, for instance:

`ssh-add /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. Definitely need more up votes !

Answer (score 1):

Along a similar line as Yuriy Pozniak's solution, I simply removed and re-added my public key, and that resolved my issue.

Modifying the ~/.ssh/config file to explicitly point the azure devops host to my private key did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks! Adding a new public key worked for me.  
This is really crazy. Last night I am able to connect from Debian machine and I wake up in the Morning and  suddenly I can't push changes to the repository. If it's  Micro$oft, it has to be crazy.