# Azure DevOps - GIT SSH Authentication - remote: Public key authentication failed

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops

I'm having trouble authenticating via ssh from my MacBook to my Azure DevOps git repository. I have setup my ssh keys as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts , and am attempting to clone my repo via the ssh url provied in my account.

> git clone myorg@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/myorg/my-repo/my-repo

but I keep getting an authentication error.

> remote: Public key authentication failed.

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

After you've checked for existing SSH keys, then you can generate a new SSH key to use for authentication, then add it.

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=vsts

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Comment: I do not. I was not able to resolve this issue. I have created private / public key pairs many times successfully so not sure what’s going on.

Answer (score 65):

Add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to `~/.ssh/config`

It is incredibly annoying because Microsoft assumes that everyone is an idiot and must have supplied the wrong public key. They just ignore all the people reporting this problem.

Also, I believe this question is a duplicate of the following:

[`ssh -T` to VSTS(Azure Devops) authenticates successfully, but `git clone` fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705553/ssh-t-to-vstsazure-devops-authenticates-successfully-but-git-clone-fails)

Comment: You saved my night!

Comment: Worked for me +1 and thanks

Comment: They have it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=current-page#q-i-have-multiple-ssh-keys--how-do-i-use-different-ssh-keys-for-different-ssh-servers-or-repos

Comment: Worked for me, was scratching my head for last 2 days.